# Why the program not found activity_main and web_view?

Tags: android, error-handling

I write a simple program and when i run the program, the program has errors. I have a activity_main.xml in layout folder but the program has error of activity_main. Why? What is the problem?

errors:  activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field
web_view cannot be resolved or is not a field

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button1;
Button button2;
WebView mWeb;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWeb= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

}
private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        //don't work something  
        }
};
}
```

Comment: just refresh and clean your project from Project->Clean Option in Eclipse IDe menu

Comment: i think imran is correct. first select your project, refresh it, and then clean & build it & run it

Comment: imran, you should write your response as an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Eclipse adds

> import android.R

to the list of imports. This is an error and it should be deleted.  Removing it sometimes resolves the described problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1. Clean you workspace and try to run again
2. Check if R.java is created in **gen** folder or not and what is the package name there?
3. Make sure your Web view and R.Java share the same package name if not , change the package name of your WebView or change in manifest.xml.
4. Try closing and opening eclipse again.